# on submit of values using .append in jQuery $_POST variable contains data in fire fox. But on chrome the $_POST variable is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

**i want to append data to already existing form. by using JQUERY as on click of Submit button as follows.**

```
  $('#submit-buildaboat').click(function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    var canvasData = document.getElementById('select-boat-color');
    var cdataurl = canvasData.toDataURL('image/png');
    var input = $("<input>")
               .attr("type", "hidden")
               .attr("name", "canvasImage").val(cdataurl);
    $('#build-a-boat').append($(input));
  });
```

It works all fine on firefox and on next page i am able to see the result and access all values from $_POST variable.

however on chrome browser the $_POST variable returns empty and even though the form is filled and data is appended.

Please advice what to do for this.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen because you submitted the form first then appended the new input. (Assuming that you are using `<input type="submit">`)

If you are appending on the click of submit button then I would say you should not use `<input type="submit">`. Use `<input type="button">` and on the click of button , append your new input field to the form and then use `form.submit()` method of jquery to submit the form.

Comment: yes actually i am playing with an already existing form.
so the submit is of the type button already. and i figured that another jquery statment is doing the .submit() function.  i dint want to change that file as its minified.
iF you had any other suggestion it would help.